# What is the best process for fetching new content using JSON?

Tags: php, json

What would be the best way to fetch new content on a website with json, I got the following system in my mind: (looped)

- client -> (do i have new content) -> server
- client <- (nope) <- server
- client -> (do i have new content) -> server
- client <- (yes, contentId x) <- server
- client -> (get content with id x) -> server
- client <- (Jim Morrison) <- server

Is this the best way? The application will be used for over 10000+ users, how does Facebook do this, and still keep everyone super fast up-to date?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One modern way to do this is to use a server-push system like WebSockets or Socket.io rather than a client-pull system like occasionally requesting an "is there something new" status.

With this type of technology there is an open connection from the client (I'm assuming it's a web browser) to the server at all times, and whenever something happens on the server, the server pushes the data out to the client directly.

For code and examples check out http://socket.io/

Not all server-side technology is compatible with this type of approach, but one very good one is Node.js which allows you to write event-driven server-side code in Javascript. See http://nodejs.org

If you choose to use Node.js on the server and want to interact with browsers, there is even Now.js (see http://nowjs.com/ ) which allows you to in effect call functions on the client from the server!

Answer (score 0):

facebook uses Peer-to-peer technology, meaning its their own cloud of information. Any server can ask any server to provide information, or where to go to get that information.

Comment: You may want to revisit your answer. It's really vague and uninformative.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do this, the most common is Polling (which you've outlined in your example), in which the client initiates the request and then closes the connection after receiving a response. The second "class" is called [HTTP Keepalive](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_persistent_connection) which has a variety (and ever growing) list of [implementations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Push_technology).

The main advantage with HTTP Keepalive is that there is no TCP connection overhead (or SSL) once the initial connection is made.

The other thing you want to look at is server [clustering](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_cluster). This is huge topic, however I suggest that you take a look at these resources to get started.

Web Server Load Balancing:

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy_balancer.html
http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpUpstreamModule

Scaling MySQL:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/replication.html

Note that there are a lot of ways to scale a site and I hope that others will post alternatives for you to evaluate.

Answer (score 0):

I would use jQuery on the browser side with this really nice plugin: http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-dotimeout-plugin/

The doTimeout functionality vastly improves on the plain JavaScript setTimeout.

Then on the PHP side have a polling function that returns 0 if no new content is available. If content is available the go ahead and return it. No sense making two trips when one will do.

Just use json_encode on the php side if content is available. Unwrap your content in the browser and append as needed.

This is a rather general overview of how to do it, but looking at the jQuery.getJSON docs should give you all the detail you need: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/